# ggplot reverse axis order for factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

This is the base plot, with months ordered *bottom-to-top* one through twelve. I want to order them *top-to-bottom* one through twelve.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(ggridges)
ggplot(weather %>% filter(temp > 50), aes(x = temp, y = as.factor(month))) + 
  geom_density_ridges()
```

[image: Capture.png]

Both of these solutions yield errors. What is the correct solution?

```
# BROKEN SOLUTION 1    
ggplot(weather %>% filter(temp > 50), aes(x = temp, y = as.factor(month))) + 
  geom_density_ridges() + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. In addition:
>   Warning messages: 1: In Ops.factor(x) : ‘-’ not meaningful for
>   factors. 2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous
>   y-axis.

and also

```
# BROKEN SOLUTION 2
ggplot(weather %>% filter(temp > 50), aes(x = temp, y = as.factor(month))) + 
  geom_density_ridges() + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(as.factor(month))))
```

> Error in is.factor(x) : object 'month' not found

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)`